# Setup .netrc for SFTP connection with private key

Tags: ssh

I have a machine that I want to setup an SFTP connection to. The SSH server is running properly, I can ssh into it from my client computer, and I can SFTP in from my smartphone. I'm just a bit confused on how to properly configure the `~/.netrc` file. The server computer is running Ubuntu, the client computer is running OSX.

Here are my main requirements for what I'm trying to configure:

1. Alias. I don't have a DNS name for the computer I'm connecting to, just the IP address. ~/.ssh/config is great because it basically assigns aliases to connections, and then specifies the hostname, port, etc. Looking at the man page for `~/.netrc`, I don't see a way to do this.
2. Private Key. This SFTP connection is validated using a private key. I don't see anything in the `~/.netrc` man page about how to specify the key.

If `~/.netrc` is the wrong way to go, what alternatives would be better?

Comment: If you're using OpenSSH's `sftp(1)` command-line client, it uses the same `~/.ssh/config` files, and not the `~/.netrc` file.  Why do you think the `~/.netrc` file needs to be used?

Comment: Mostly because I was googling the wrong thing haha. thanks.